# Possible to monitor twitter in my app?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an app, where the user can submit their mood (from 0-10), and then i count the sum of all the submitted values.

If i create a twitter account (lets call it @mood).

Can i then build a service, who monitors twitter, so the user can write (in twitter) like "@mood 6"

And i get the value "6" in my application?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor and LINQ 2 SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look into the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage) and the [Developer Center](http://dev.twitter.com/) for creating your mood post.

Getting the information should be easy using the [feed of the twitter account](http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/41754227.rss).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Your Twitter application should authenticate as the "@Mood" user several times a day (the frequency depends on how many tweets you expect to be getting.

You would then monitor the "Mentions" timeline (easily done through the Twitter API) to retrieve the messages you describe.